# Examples for ipython backends in other languages?

Tags: clojure, ipython, jupyter-notebook

At PyCon2013, I found out that it is possible for the ipython notebook to be used for other languages bu writing a different backend. In the ipython docs, I have seen the page on the protocol, and mention that servers have been written for perl and ruby. I am interested in one for clojure.

Where would I find the code for a sample non-python backend to evaluate if a clojure backend is a practical thing, in terms of the time and expertise I can devote to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240747/sending-messages-from-other-languages-to-an-ipython-kernel

Answer (score 2):

[ihaskell-notebook](https://github.com/creswick/ihaskell-notebook) integrates Haskell into IPython.

[IHaskell](http://gibiansky.github.io/IHaskell/) wraps around IPython to run Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2854 will give you a quick recap of the last change and link to a [ruby kernel](https://github.com/minrk/iruby). I drafted a [node kernel with some explanation](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4279371/node-kernel.ipynb) some time ago, it might need to be updated to work with last IPython and last node. [IClosure](https://github.com/cosmin/IClojure) have take some code from IPython and made a POC of clojure working, we'll be happy if the kernel was ported to work with last IPython as it would get all the new improvement with autosave and so on. I never saw the perl kernel.

Don't hesitate to open an issue of a PR on github with a draft of Clojure kernel (even if the PR won't be merged in main repo, it help to see the code), we'll be happy to help.

Just to insist a little more for other reader, as it is often not well understood:

With current dev version, you do **not** need to **fork** IPython, **nor modify** it source code to have it work with a non-python kernel, not even have to write python.

Comment: Hi Matt, for writing a iPython Kernel one does need to know only how to use zeroMQ and read the iPython communication specification?

I'm interested in trying to write one for Cling (a clang-based C++ pseudo-interpreter).

Comment: Have a look on [IPython ml](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2014-January/012919.html) similar question have been asked with link to resources.